# R - character string with week-Year: week is lost when converting to Date format

Tags: r, datetime, string-formatting

I have a character string of the date in Year-week format as such:

```
weeks.strings <- c("2002-26", "2002-27", "2002-28", "2002-29", "2002-30", "2002-31")
```

However, converting this character to Date class results in a loss of week identifier:

```
> as.Date(weeks.strings, format="%Y-%U")
[1] "2002-08-28" "2002-08-28" "2002-08-28" "2002-08-28" "2002-08-28"
[6] "2002-08-28"
```

As shown above, the format is converted into year- concatenated with today's date, so any information about the original week is lost (ex - when using the format function or strptime to try and coerce back into the original format.

One solution I found in a help group is to specify the day of the week:

```
as.Date(weeks.strings, format="%Y-%u %U")
[1] "2002-02-12" "2002-02-19" "2002-02-26" "2002-03-05" "2002-01-02"
[6] "2002-01-09"
```

But it looks like this results in incorrect week numbering (doesn't match the original string).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Dates don't have a week identifier... can you add what you expected the output to be?

Comment: Joshua - I have a value associated with each weekly data point. I want to be able to plot week vs value, so retaining the data as a date object is important to me for plotting purposes. The expected output is the same as the original character string, but of class Date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to add a weekday to your `weeks.strings` in order to make the dates unambiguous (adapted from [Jim Holtman's answer on R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e15/help/11/07/0416.html)).

```
as.Date(paste(weeks.strings,1),"%Y-%U %u")
```

As pointed out in the comments, the Date class is not appropriate if the dates span a long horizon because--at some point--the chosen weekday will not exist in the first/last week of the year.  In that case you could use a numeric vector where the whole portion is the year and the decimal portion is the fraction of weeks/year.  For example:

```
wkstr <- sprintf("%d-%02d", rep(2000:2012,each=53), 0:52)
yrwk <- lapply(strsplit(wkstr, "-"), as.numeric)
yrwk <- sapply(yrwk, function(x) x[1]+x[2]/53)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I found an error with this method. A string with week 00 in it ex - "2003-00" returns as NA after applying this function. Though perhaps the error is in having week 0 in the first place?

Comment: @zzk: week 0 is fine. The `NA` means there wasn't a Monday in the first week of 2003.  Try using a number other than 1 in the `paste` command.

Comment: yup that occurred to me after I posted. The problem is that I have a large lists of dates. In some years there are no mondays in the first week and sometimes there are no fridays in the last week of the year. So I wind up getting about the same number of NAs no matter which number I use.

Comment: Then you can't use the Date class and have equidistant dates between weeks.  How about just using a number, where the whole portion is the year and the decimal portion is the week (fraction of a year)?

Comment: @zzk: what is the range of your "weeks", 00-53?

Comment: looks like 00-52. I'm not seeing 53 in the dataset

Comment: @zzk: see my edit. You should be able to create your plot with `yrwk` and label the axis with `wkstr`.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, there's no unique solution, since each week could be represented by any of up to 7 different dates.  That said, here's one idea:

```
weeks.strings <- c("2002-26", "2002-27", "2002-28", "2002-29",
                   "2002-30", "2002-31")

x <- as.Date("2002-1-1", format="%Y-%m-%d") + (0:52*7)
x[match(weeks.strings, format(x, "%Y-%U"))]
# [1] "2002-07-02" "2002-07-09" "2002-07-16" "2002-07-23"
# [5] "2002-07-30" "2002-08-06"
```

Comment: I don't care which day of the week is specified, as long as its consistent. I just want to plot the frequency of weekly data.